# Wrapping ctypes structure in python class causes memory errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to make the functionality of a C library available in python with the help of ctypes. Although I already have a good amount of progress, I need to question my approach due to some memory problems.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible while I still can reproduce the problem.
Given following definitions in the C library:

```c
struct _vector {
  double *v;
  uint dim;
  void *owner;
};

_vector* new_pointer_vector(double* src, uint dim); //uint is just a typedef for unsigned
void print_vector(const _vector* v);
```

I can simply use this in python as follows:

```
import ctypes


class CStructVector(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('v', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
        ('dim', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('owner', ctypes.c_void_p)
    ]


lib = ctypes.CDLL('../mylib.so')
new_pointer_vector = lib.new_pointer_vector
new_pointer_vector.restype = ctypes.POINTER(CStructVector)
new_pointer_vector.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_uint]
print_vector = lib.print_vector
print_vector.restype = None
print_vector.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(CStructVector)]
```

Now I can do the following in python to create a vector instance based on a list, which works as expected:

```
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
cx = (ctypes.c_double * len(x))(*x)
v = new_pointer_vector(cx, len(x))
print_vector(v)
# Output: (1.0000e+00 2.0000e+00 3.0000e+00 5.0000e+00)
```

The goal of my project is to hide most of the ctypes stuff, so that the user has it as easy as possible. What follows seems to mess with the memory in some way I don't understand, as you can see in the output.

```py
class Vector():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        clst = (ctypes.c_double * len(lst))(*lst)
        self.cptr = new_pointer_vector(clst, len(lst))

    def print(self):
        print_vector(self.cptr)


x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
v = Vector(x)
v.print()
# Output: (6.12362e-310 2.0000e+00 3.0000e+00 5.0000e+00)
```

As I mentioned, my project has progressed quite far at this point and way more complex programs have worked as expected in python. I hope for any hints to how I can further analyze this problem and hopefully fix it. 
In case this might be a suggestion: Using the special `_as_parameter_` attribute in my Vector class instead of `cptr`, so that I can pass `self` to the `print_vector()` method doesn't help.

If you have ideas on how to achieve the same goal (the three lines in the non-working example) in a different way, I'm happy to hear them as well.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you make `clst` an attribute of your `Vector` class instead of a local variable?  (I.e. replace `clst = ...` with `self.clst = ...`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Works like a charm, thanks a lot! From a C perspective this seems kinda obvious now, sad that I couldn't think of that myself. 
Since I have a lot more of classes like `Vector` (around 25 atm), I'm looking for a more general solution. My approach now is to have an class-wide array `_refs` which stores values like `clst` to ensure its existence during the lifetime of the object. Works for now, but I'm always open for other ideas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to assign `clst` as an attribute in the `__init__` method of the `Vector` class:

```py
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.clst = (ctypes.c_double * len(lst))(*lst)
        self.cptr = new_pointer_vector(self.clst, len(lst))
```

Leaving it as a local variable meant that Python could garbage-collect it once the `__init__` method finished executing.  Evidently that was causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for reposting it as an answer, I didn't know I should've done this. To clearify what "was causing problems." means: The memory which holds the list in python mustn't be cleared / collected, because the C function only assigns pointer of said memory to `v` instead of copying the values (since `v` is defined as an `double*`)

Comment: @Plexian: I'm glad I helped.  The comment I posted was just the first thing that came to mind: I don't have your C library to hand and didn't write a simple one just to test out the change, but at the same time I didn't fancy writing it an answer on the off-chance it didn't help.